# Typescript import text file "error TS2307: Cannot find module"

Tags: typescript, import, module

I wanted to import a text file to my typescript file and simply print it.

**index.ts** file:

```
import d from "./a.txt";
console.log(d);
```

**txt.d.ts** file:

```
declare module "*.txt" {
  const value: string;
  export default value;
}
```

**tsconfig.json** file:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "system"
  }
}
```

**package.json** file:

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "tsc": "tsc",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "typescript": "^3.0.1"
  }
}
```

but it's giving me this **error**:

> > tsc "index.ts"
>
> index.ts:1:15 - error TS2307: Cannot find module './a.txt'.
>
> 1 import d from "./a.txt";
>
> npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE npm ERR! errno 2 npm ERR! test@1.0.0 tsc:
>   `tsc "index.ts"` npm ERR! Exit status 2 npm ERR! npm ERR! Failed at
>   the test@1.0.0 tsc script. npm ERR! This is probably not a problem
>   with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR!
>   C:\Users\SOstad\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2018-08-15T16_45_37_115Z-debug.log

file structure:

```
Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
d-----        8/15/2018  11:50 AM                node_modules
-a----        8/15/2018  12:40 PM             12 .gitignore
-a----        8/15/2018  12:22 PM             20 a.txt
-a----        8/15/2018  12:45 PM            112 index.js
-a----        8/15/2018  12:25 PM             43 index.ts
-a----        8/15/2018  11:50 AM            363 package-lock.json
-a----        8/15/2018  11:51 AM            270 package.json
-a----        8/15/2018  12:25 PM             59 tsconfig.json
-a----        8/15/2018  12:25 PM             78 txt.d.ts
```

Answer (score 3):

Since you just run `tsc index.ts`, nothing is forcing `txt.d.ts` to be loaded.  Given that you have a `tsconfig.json` file, you probably mean to run `tsc -p .`.  This still won't work at runtime unless you're using a bundler that bundles the text file in the format you're assuming.

Comment: so what should I do?
add webpack?
is there any way to do it with just typescript?

Comment: If you want to use an import, you have to use a bundler; Webpack will probably work, though I've never used it myself and don't know the details.  Your only other option would be to not use an import and instead use the API of your target environment to read the file from the correct location; in Node this would be `fs.readFile`, while in the browser it would be `XMLHttpRequest` or the Fetch API.

Comment: I add webpack to my node application and now it works. thanks